# Scroll to top of the page after redirect rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Look I have website prototype here you can check https://arcane-beyond-35849.herokuapp.com/about

For example if you scroll down `about page` and then click on some link to go to another page, let's say you click `restore car process` link on  the left(but don't forget to scroll down the page)
So then you will go to another page. But browser (my definetely) remembers scroll position. So I go to the middle of another page. How do I fix this?

Comment: This is most likely an issue with turbolinks or some other form of partial page replacement - "normal" synchronous links will always scroll to the top as the browser does not know that the content of new document has anything to do with old one.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/66

Comment: Your website prototype is down.